# How to get the JavaScript Object from the given string?

Tags: javascript

How to get the Object from a string?

I written a localStorage util, in it there are `get` and `set` methods.

in the set method:

```
function fnGet(name){

var getVal=storage.getItem(name);
if(getVal==null){
  return console.log('the localstorage did\'t have'+name);
}
if((getVal.split(':-:')).lenght>1){
  return eval('('+getVal.split(':-:')[0]+')');
}
  return getVal.split(':-:')[0];
}
```

You can ignore the `:-:`, it is the separator of the saved data and timestamp.

there is a problem, if the data is stored a JavaScript Object, such like this:

`'{"pk":1,"username":"test01","email":"","first_name":"","last_name":""}:-:1521381469910'`

when I use the get method, it will become like this:

`'{"pk":1,"username":"test01","email":"","first_name":"","last_name":""}'`

How can I get to the JavaScript Object?

How to optimize my get method?

Comment: Rather than using `:-:` as a separator, consider wrapping your data again in another object for the metadata, and stringify/parsing the whole thing into/out from localStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.parse` on your response from the store. localStorage stores everything as strings so you would need to stringify the object at first, as Im supposed you do as otherwise you wouldnt have been able to save it to the store.

Then to retrieve it you would need to parse it to get the javascript object again.

Comment: in there are two case, if the data is a string like: 'aaaaa', can not use the JSON.parse.

Comment: @244boy in your save/set function, JSON.stringify the data, and `'aaaaa'` would be `'"aaaaa"'`, which can be parsed

Comment: exactly, if you `JSON.stringify()` when you saves your object, it can always become parsed, but your question stated if you save a javascript object, `'aaaa'` is not an object, its a string.

Comment: "*localStorage stores everything as JSON*" - no. localStorage only stores strings. It's the program that uses JSON in these strings.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Use `JSON.parse()` instead of `eval`; it's not only safer, but more descriptive as to what your intent is.  Note: this requires using `JSON.stringify()` on the data being saved in localStorage
2. Correct your spelling errors; you would never get to the eval/parser block because your `length` was spelled "lenght"

```js
function fnGet(name) {

  let getVal = storage.getItem(name)
  if (getVal == null) {
    return console.log(`the localstorage did't have: ${name}`);
  }
  
  let val = getVal.split(':-:');      // for performance cache the split
  if (val.length > 1) {               // Spelling error: "lenght" -> length
    return JSON.parse(val[0]);
  }
  return val[0];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

LocalStorage saves the data stringified. So you should use `JSON.parse(yourVariable)` to get the data back as JSON

Answer (score -1):

```
function fnGet(name) {

    var getVal = storage.getItem(name);
    if (getVal == null) {
        return console.log('the localstorage did\'t have' + name);
    }
    if ((getVal.split(':-:')).lenght > 1) {
        return eval('(' + JSON.parse(getVal.split(':-:')[0]) + ')');
    }
    return getVal.split(':-:')[0];
}
```

all you needed was JSON.parse which takes a string as an argument and if its a valid object string ,returns an object else throws an error